# Will this power supply be able to power raspberry pis

Tags: power-supply, raspberry-pi

I don’t know if this is the correct place to ask but I was wondering if this power supply will be able to power 4 raspberry pis.

Here is the link: https://m.aliexpress.com/item/32946637768.html?spm=a2g0n.shopcart-amp.item.32946637768&

I’m planning on making a pi cluster and I want to power the pis with some sort of power supply. I don’t know if this will work but if anyone knows of any other good power supplies, let me know. Thanks!!!

Comment: Probably not, but it has no specs whatsoever besides "DC Power Supply Hole".

Comment: Please add the specifications of this power supply (which seems to be just an unspecified USB hub) to the question. A question on StackExchange needs to be self-contained and it should not rely on external links. Just placing a link to a product will make this question unusable when the link stops working. If there are no specifications, we cannot help you. Shopping questions are also not allowed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No                            .

Comment: Do you know of any I could use?

Comment: Raspberry recommend a 2.5 A power supply for the board (assuming you don't enable any significant power savings modes). So you need a power supply that can supply 5 V at at least 10 A. There are many supplies available.